# apt-get getting error E: Internal Error, No file name for open-vm-tools:amd64

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg, dependencies

I upgraded Ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04

I get this error with the package `open-vm-tools`  whenever I try to do anything apt-get related, for example:

```
#sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-server:
 ubuntu-server depends on open-vm-tools; however:
  Package open-vm-tools is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ubuntu-server
```

So far I've tried:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get install -fy
sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

And the error is still there, any ideas?

I tried to remove the package, but the ubuntu-server depends on it, I'm not sure if removing ubuntu-server would break my system.

Edit:

Running: `sudo dpkg --configure open-vm-tools`

```
Setting up open-vm-tools (2:10.2.0-3~ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
udevadm trigger is not permitted while udev is unconfigured.
dpkg: error processing package open-vm-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu11) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 open-vm-tools
```

Running: `apt-cache policy open-vm-tools`

```
open-vm-tools:
  Installed: 2:10.2.0-3~ubuntu0.16.04.1
  Candidate: 2:10.2.0-3~ubuntu0.16.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 2:10.2.0-3~ubuntu0.16.04.1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2:10.0.7-3227872-2ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Running: `sudo dpkg --configure udev`

```
sudo dpkg --configure udev
dpkg: error processing package udev (--configure):
 package udev is already installed and configured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 udev
```

Running: `sudo apt-cache policy udev`

```
sudo apt-cache policy udev
udev:
  Installed: 229-4ubuntu21.28
  Candidate: 229-4ubuntu21.28
  Version table:
 *** 229-4ubuntu21.28 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     229-4ubuntu21.27 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
     229-4ubuntu4 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

---

Running: `dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'`

```
dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
+++-=====================================-===============================================-============-===============================================================================
ic  libapache2-mod-php5                   5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.29                          amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)
ic  libpcrecpp0:amd64                     1:8.31-2ubuntu2.3                               amd64        Perl 5 Compatible Regular Expression Library - C++ runtime files
ic  mysql-server-5.5                      5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2                         amd64        MySQL database server binaries and system database setup
rF  open-vm-tools                         2:10.2.0-3~ubuntu0.16.04.1                      amd64        Open VMware Tools for virtual machines hosted on VMware (CLI)
ic  perl-modules                          5.18.2-2ubuntu1.7                               all          Core Perl modules
ic  php5-fpm                              5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.29                          amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (FPM-CGI binary)
ic  systemd-services                      204-5ubuntu20.31                                amd64        systemd runtime services
iU  ubuntu-server                         1.361.4                                         amd64        The Ubuntu Server system
```

---

Running: `sudo dpkg -P  systemd-services`

```
(Reading database ... 118245 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing systemd-services (204-5ubuntu20.31) ...
Purging configuration files for systemd-services (204-5ubuntu20.31) ...
```

Running: `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-server:
 ubuntu-server depends on open-vm-tools; however:
  Package open-vm-tools is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ubuntu-server
```

Comment: What do you get if you run `sudo dpkg --configure open-vm-tools`? And what is the output of `apt-cache policy open-vm-tools`?

Comment: (Sorry the indentation  in the comments gets messed up)

Comment: @Kulfy See edited post

Comment: What about `sudo dpkg --configure udev` and `apt-cache policy udev`?

Comment: @Kulfy See the output in the post

Comment: And `dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'`

Comment: @nobody See the post

Comment: @Kulfy Doesn't make any sense It can't install open-vm-tools because udev is not configured, but udev is configured.

Comment: `sudo dpkg -P  systemd-services` then try again `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: @nobody See post.

Comment: Kind of late but where's the error in the title? It's not listed anywhere. This is bad because a google search leads here with no helpful information.

Answer (score 0):

First of all; make a backup. Let us try to fix this. the packages with status

```
ic
```

seem to be packages from trusty. strange status.

```
sudo dpkg -P libapache2-mod-php5 libpcrecpp0:amd64 mysql-server-5.5 php5-fpm
```

then  try to install perl-modules

```
wget -c http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/p/perl/perl-modules-5.22_5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6_all.deb
```

I hope at least wget is working.

```
sudo dpkg -i perl-modules-5.22_5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6_all.deb
```

the same for  open-vm-tools

```
wget -c http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/o/open-vm-tools/open-vm-tools_10.2.0-3~ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb
```

this is for 64-bit.

for 32-bit

```
wget -c http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/o/open-vm-tools/open-vm-tools_10.2.0-3~ubuntu0.16.04.1_i386.deb
```

use dpkg to install it.
No error?

```
sudo apt-get -f install  && sudo apt-get update
```

Then finish the upgrade with

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: This fixed all the ic's except the perl-modules, after installing with dpkg it still shows as ic. Also after I installed open-vm-tools, the same error shows. So now there's open-vm-tools:iF, perl-modules:ic and ubuntu-server:iU.

Comment: Test your hard drive with smartmontools from a live Linux.

Comment: I don't know if that would change anything but this is a virutal server in AWS.

Comment: So I don't think the hard drive would be the culprit here.

Comment: I uninstalled the perl modules and installed them again, that fixed them, only the open-vm-tools error left.